# Confusion in Spring Cloud microservice architecture

Tags: microservices, spring-cloud

I am trying to create a spring cloud microservice by using spring boot framework.

- I created a REST microservice by using spring boot framework.
- I also created an Eureka server as another spring boot project. And I registered microservice to the Eureka server.
- And I created another spring boot project for Zuul. This project also registered to Eureka server.

My Eureka server is running with 2 registered spring boot projects. Eureka server UI is properly working.

Here My confusion is that, am I following standard way of developing spring cloud microservice?

Since all documentations show this type of spring cloud development. And some blog shows spring cloud in another structure. So I am totally confused about whether I am going in proper way of spring cloud microservice development?

I am new to spring cloud. Can anyone clarify if my current architecture (Creating eureka server and microservice registration as client(Zuul also)) is proper???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your architecture is fine, but it still depends on your purpose.

Quote from this article - [Spring Cloud Netflix](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_spring_cloud_netflix), there are several common components used to build a micro-service architecture with Spring Cloud Netflix.

- Service Discovery (Eureka)
- Intelligent Routing (Zuul)
- Circuit Breaker (Hystrix)
- Client Side Load Balancing (Ribbon)

In my opinion, all these 4 components are required. So maybe you can explain what you want to achieve such as do you want to provide a service to many people or applications? Does your application need to be scaled out someday? Or if your service doesn't response after a long time, what will you do?

Comment: Yes . I got it. I had confusions in those one tool- hystrix. I thought that it is only for inter service communication. But now I got the proper idea from one blog - https://luizkowalski.net/netflix-oss-a-beginners-guide-pt4/. Now I understood about the all when goes through your statements. Thank you for your proper response and guidance.

Comment: Regarding to my this architecture doubt, I suffering  from another section. If you have time, can you please take a look at this following question? . Link is - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47506077/spring-cloud-microservice-architecture-confusion.